# Disable no-use-before-define rule for a specific variable/function name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I use Mui as the design-system of my react project and have therefore often this component architecture:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const Component = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      background: theme.palette.background.gradient,
      minHeight: '100vh'
    }
  }
})
```

But when I add eslint I got the error `'useStyles' was used before it was defined`. I know that I can disable this rule for all variables by using the config:

```json
  "no-use-before-define": ["error", { "variables": false }]
```

But is there a way to disable it only for variables/functions with the name `useStyles`?

Answer (score 1):

A good way out of this is to use module functionality of JavaScript.

Instead of creating this at the bottom of your file, create structure as such


 MyReactComponent

  |- index.js

 |- styles.js

This allows you to import your styles.js (your styles function) file at the top of your file keeping your code clean. Don't worry about having to do complex imports, I suggest you to use webpack's function [Resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/), allowing you to create simplified imports.

`import MyReactComponent from 'Components/MyReactComponent'`

You don't have to mention index.js in the import as it's the default file that engine will look for.

Comment: That was also an idea but it means for me to create hundreds of extra files for just a few lines of css.

Comment: So, you are left with two options - put the useStyles on top of the file, right under the imports, or fork eslint or crate a eslint plugin, and create your own rules - I find that a useful skill! 

https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules - developer's guide
https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/ - creating a plugin